# How to programmatically add objects/views on a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've been using [Interface Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) and storyboard to make my application, but for this signature capturing API, everything was done in code.

I'm trying to implement it to my application, but I can't figure out how to add an UIView and Buttons on to my scrollview.

I got it to appear in my view controller, but it isn't connected to the scrollview at all; it appears on top.

Here's my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat padding = self.view.frame.size.width/15;

    UIView *autoGraphView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 300, 280, 160)] autorelease];
    autoGraphView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    autoGraphView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    autoGraphView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [autoGraphView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:autoGraphView];

    self.autoGraph = [T1Autograph autographWithView:autoGraphView delegate:self];
    [autoGraph setLicenseCode:@"4fabb271f7d93f07346bd02cec7a1ebe10ab7bec"];
    [autoGraph setShowDate:YES];
    [autoGraph setShowHash:YES];

    UIButton *clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // init withFrame:CGRectMake (50, 300, 200, 60)];
    [clearButton setFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 480, 130, 30)];
    [clearButton setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clearButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:clearButton];

    UIButton *autoDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // initWithFrame:CGRectMake (50, 300, 200, 60)];
    [autoDone setFrame:CGRectMake(150 + padding, 480, 130, 30)];
    [autoDone setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [autoDone setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [autoDone addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:autoDone];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the subviews to the scrollview, if the root view of your viewcontroller is not the scrollview, you need to get access to it one way or another, typically through an IBOutlet, and add them that way